# Axios replay request Promise including .then()

Tags: javascript, axios

Is it possible to replay an axios request (Promise) and execute the function defined in .then?

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(res => return res, err => {
 if(err.response.status === 401) {
  // something like this, but so it would fire the .then on completion
  return axios(err.config)
 }
})
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need make this config:

```
  validateStatus: function validateStatus(status) {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300 || status == 401;
  }
```

Then when status is 401, it may execute the function defined in .then.